# Dictionary to Dataframe with list as value

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to create a dataframe from two dictionaries with matching keys with the values in neighboring columns.

I have two dictionaries:

```
pl = {'seq1' : ['actgcta', 'cggctatcg'], 'seq2': ['cgatcgatca'], 'seq3': ['cgatcagt', 'cgataataat']}

pr = {'seq1' : ['cagtatacga', 'attacgat', 'atcgactagt'], 'seq2': ['cgatcgatca'], 'seq3': ['cgatcagt']}
```

I am trying to create a dataframe that looks like this (please forgive the crude figure):

```
seq1 |['actgcta','cggctatcg']    |['cagtatacga', 'attacgat', 'atcgactagt']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
seq2 |['cgatcgatca']             |['cgatcgatca']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
seq3 |['cgatcagt', 'cgataataat'] |['cgatcagt']
```

I have tried working with `pd.DataFrame` , `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` , and played with various `orient` args, but have had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.Series, [pl, pr]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                           0                                   1
seq1    [actgcta, cggctatcg]  [cagtatacga, attacgat, atcgactagt]
seq2            [cgatcgatca]                        [cgatcgatca]
seq3  [cgatcagt, cgataataat]                          [cgatcagt]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to import the dictionaries into dataframes, you r lists must be of the same length, which they are not. So we must first put the lists into a single list of list. Then we can merge the dataframes with  simple concatenation:

```
import pandas as pd

pl = {'seq1' : ['actgcta', 'cggctatcg'], 'seq2': ['cgatcgatca'], 'seq3': ['cgatcagt', 'cgataataat']}
pr = {'seq1' : ['cagtatacga', 'attacgat', 'atcgactagt'], 'seq2': ['cgatcgatca'], 'seq3': ['cgatcagt']}

for keys in pl.keys():
    pl[keys] = [pl[keys]]
for keys in pr.keys():
    pr[keys] = [pr[keys]]
df = pd.DataFrame(pl)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pr)
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1])
print(df2.transpose())
```